# Euclid Math Type One character

Tags: fonts

I want to use just a single character (the capital G) from the Euclid Math One font in a latex document.
How can I do that without using Xe or LualaTeX?
Here is the preamble:

```
\documentclass[sunil1]{sunil} %See documentation for other class options
\HeadingsChapterSection
\usepackage{fixltx2e,fix-cm}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx,wrapfig,lipsum}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{MnSymbol}
\setlength{\textfloatsep}{2pt plus 1pt minus 1pt}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{placeins}
\setcounter{chapter}{+0}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}


\newcommand{\squeezeup}
 {\vspace{-1cm}}
\newcommand{\squeezedown}
 {\vspace{-3mm}}
```

On using @egreg solution mentioned below I get the error: Too many math alphabets used in version normal

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! For the benefit of the readers of this site who are not familiar with "EuclidTypeOne", would you mind providing a brief explanation as to what it is?

Comment: I just want to use a symbol from the font Euclid math type one.

Comment: Do you mean [this Roman G](http://i.stack.imgur.com/4fH6Q.png) or [this calligraphic G](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Terpx.png)?

Comment: @egreg Yes I mean the calligraphic G. I assume this is the small version of this one [http://ufonts.com/previewi/euclid-math-one_font_133479.gif] Thanks

Comment: To get code to display *as code*, highlight the code with your mouse, and then click on the `{}` icon above the edit box.

Comment: Any clue for where to find `sunil.cls`? I found one at https://cyberaide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/papers/11-greenit-bookch/sunil.cls but when I add my code below I get no error.

Comment: @VishalMinhas Start with removing the call to `MnSymbol`.

Comment: @egreg Thanks so much!! I finally have the Euclid G in my output without the MnSymbol. sunil.cls was provided to me by someone. I am not sure about the source though.

Comment: @egreg Everything is correct, but now I realize that in some other chapter the package MnSymbol  is required. Only one symbol `\ntwoheadrightarrow`
So can I use the package for one chapter and override for some other chapter?

Answer (score 5):

The calligraphic G from the Euler fonts is easily available:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\eulG}{\textnormal{\usefont{U}{eus}{m}{n}G}}

\begin{document}

$\eulG\ne\mathcal{G}$; let's try a subscript: $A_{\eulG}$.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: On using your solution I am getting this error: Too many math alphabets used in version normal.  Any help?

Comment: @VishalMinhas Since this macro doesn't define new math alphabets, I don't think it's the cause of the problem.